# Как зафиксировать событие входа (авторизации) пользователя в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно записывать в БД дату входа (успешной авторизации) пользователя сайта.
Планирую использовать для самой записи события и слушателя (Event & Listener) . Но не могу понять где именно вызывать event после входа пользователя. Наверное нужно писать какой то метод Auth/LoginController . Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше это реализовать
Решение [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970105/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5) у меня не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
Использовал [встроенный евент](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#events) *Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login.*

В `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider.php` в `listener` добавил

```
'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [ 'App\Listeners\UserEventListener' ]
```

Cоздал *App\Listeners\UserEventListener.php* и в нем в методе `handle` код который выполняется после входа юзера.

Comment: отметьте Ваш ответ решением, для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от текста ответа. после этого галка станет зеленой, что означает, что Вы приняли ответ и он является решением Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Было бы не плохо твой код увидеть, посмотреть добавил ли ты Событие и Слушателя в файл App\Providers\EventServiceProvider список $listen

Comment: Использовал встроенный евент Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login . Сделал следующим образом:

в **EventServiceProvider.php** добавил
        `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\UserEventListener'
        ],`

создал **App\Listeners\UserEventListener.php** и в нем в методе **handle**  код который выполняется после входа юзера... Все работает)